# I am getting this error message: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am new to python.
I am getting this error when I run the below code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-cdb5a334e110> in <module>
     16 
     17 duplicates_removed = clean_strings
---> 18 duplicates_removed = list(dict.fromkeys(duplicates_removed))
     19 print(duplicates_removed)

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

**code**

```
import re
def remove_punctuation(value):
    return re.sub('[!#?]', '', value)

clean_ops = [str.strip, remove_punctuation, str.title]

def clean_strings(strings, ops):
    result = []
    for value in strings:
        for function in ops:
            value = function(value)
        result.append(value)
    return result

clean_strings(states_1, clean_ops)

duplicates_removed = clean_strings
duplicates_removed = list(dict.fromkeys(duplicates_removed))
print(duplicates_removed)
```

Comment: Additionally, for removing duplicates you can go for `duplicates_removed = set(duplicates_removed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clean_strings(states_1, clean_ops)` call the function but not saving the return value to any variable.

`duplicates_removed = clean_strings` just point to the function and not calling it, becuse it not have ()

Fix:

```
duplicates_removed = clean_strings(states_1, clean_ops)
duplicates_removed = list(dict.fromkeys(duplicates_removed))
print(duplicates_removed)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error line is

```py
duplicates_removed = clean_strings
```

You probably want to store the result of the function in `duplicates removed`. For that you need to do:

```py
duplicates_removed = clean_strings(states_1, clean_ops)
```

Notice how I "merged" the line before.
In your original line, you actually put a function object inside `duplicates_removed` - it's not the result of the function, yet a the function object itself.

The line `clean_strings(states_1, clean_ops)` calls to the function, but does not store anywhere the results of the function

I also don't see where you define `states_1` in your code, I guess it's before?

Answer (score 1):

```
duplicates_removed = clean_strings
duplicates_removed = list(dict.fromkeys(duplicates_removed))
print(duplicates_removed)
```

You are passing the reference of the function `clean_strings` to the `dict.fromkeys`! ^^

This:

```
duplicates_removed = clean_strings(states_1, clean_ops)
duplicates_removed = list(dict.fromkeys(duplicates_removed))
print(duplicates_removed)
```

would resolve the problem :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by passing the reference of the function clean_string to the dict.fromkets

Comment: clean_string is the name of the function, so it is like a variable which refers to the function itself, not to an iterable. The **result** of that function, otherwise, is an iterable (in this case, a list).